# Ionic http data empty in html

Tags: ionic-framework

```
 users: any = [];

runHttp(){
   this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    this.users = Object.values(data);
     })
   }
```

and html screen :

```
ion-button (click)="runHttp()" >User çek</ion-button>
    <ion-list *ngFor='let user of users'>
      <ion-item>
      <h2>{{user.email}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

but h2{{user.email}} is empty in html screen why ?

Comment: I think the error is from the format of the data. Can you give an example of what `data` in the subscribe() function look like.

Comment: https://ibb.co/5rHXyz9

Comment: Thanks. Can you add it directly to your question as text ? So that I can copy/paste it to try on my own. I think `this.users = data.data;` might works.